# Android - Fetching user GPS location without application context

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to simply fetch the user's location when a button is pressed in Android App.
My app uses data binding meaning that we have:

- A single main activity
- Fragments (views)
- Viewmodels which interact with my repos

The problem is that my button presses are handled in the **Viewmodel** but I can only get GPS location in the **View**.
This is how I get the GPS location in a Fragment, using this class https://github.com/Miserlou/Cop-Recorder-2/blob/master/src/org/ale/coprecord/MyLocation.java  :

```java
LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
    @Override
    public void gotLocation(Location location){
        newSessionViewModel.getPositionObtained().postValue(location);
            }
        };

MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
gotLocation = myLocation.getLocation(this.getContext(), locationResult);
```

The problem is `this.getContext()`. Fragments have access to the context, but my Viewmodels don't.

Therefore to fetch the location in my Viewmodel I have to go from my Viewmodel, to my View, and back to my Viewmodel, as you can see above, which is annoying and ugly.

Other solutions I've found also require a context to be passed:

```java
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
```

So my question is, what's the easiest, fastest way to just fetch the current user's location in a Viewmodel? Or should I just pass a the context to a global variable in a static class and reuse that in my Viewmodels? That might be faster and easier.

Comment: "but my Viewmodels don't" -- if you are using the Jetpack `ViewModel` system, use `AndroidViewModel` instead of `ViewModel` as the base class to have a `Context`.

Comment: Why don't you use [Google Play Location Services](https://developer.android.com/training/location)?

Comment: Just wanted to know why don't you fetch location in fragment itself? and use the local to bind the data to the view

Comment: @ManojMohanty the fragment is the view, I have been fetching location in the fragment and it involves sending a call to the fragment from my VM, getting the location, and then sending it back to my VM, which is ridiculous in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and the easiest way of getting location updates is fetching location updates via [Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/training/location)

Hope this helps!